# Get random entities (including children) using Guid.NewGuid() in .Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, random, entity-framework-core

I need to get some random entities from database, using EF Core, including some children entities. First, I used this example :

```
var entities = await context.Entities
    .Include(p => p.Children1)
    .Include(p => p.Children2)
    .Include(p => p.Children3)
    .OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Take(4)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The problem with this is that Guid.NewGuid() return children randomly, and is not assigned only for main entities. So, sometimes I get Children1, sometimes not, and I need to apply this random interogation only for the main.

I find a solution, but I think this is not the best one. I need to know if a better solution exists. First time, I get the ids for some random main entities, then I get all their entities, including children (this is bad because I do 2 requests into database):

```
var ids = context.Entities
    .OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Take(4)
    .ToListAsync();

var entities = context.Entities
    .Include(p => p.Children1)
    .Include(p => p.Children2)
    .Include(p => p.Children3)
    .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: If this is true then this is an EF bug. Use the latest version and/or report the bug.

Comment: Currently, this is the only way to achieve your requirement, you could track this issue [OrderBy Guid.NewGuid() does not work when using Include with Many to Many? #5583](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5583)